# Где в коде реализуется статический полиморфизм?

Tags: c++, полиморфизм

Препод задал вопрос, в какой строчке этого кода (C++) реализуется статический полиморфизм? Также препод сказал, что тут существует статический полиморфизм в неявном виде.

```
  #include"stdafx.h"
  #include<iostream>
  #include<clocale>
  #include<conio.h>
  #include<ctime>

  using namespace std;

  class pulsometer
  {
  public:
  int pulse;
  int calories;
  int timer;
  void show_pulse(void);
  void show_calories(void);

  void show_timer() 
  {
         cout << "Таймер: " << timer << endl;
  }

  void start_timer()
  {
        timer = 10;
  }
  };

  void pulsometer::show_pulse(void)

  {
  pulsometer::pulse = rand() % 45 + 90;
  cout << "Пульс: " << pulse << endl;
  }

  void pulsometer::show_calories(void)

  {
  pulsometer::calories = rand() % 1000;
  cout << "Сожжено: " << calories << " ККал" <<  endl;
  }

  int_tmain(intargc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
         setlocale(0,"");
         srand( time( 0 ) ); 
         pulsometer polar;

         polar.start_timer();
         polar.show_timer();

         polar.show_pulse();
         polar.show_calories();

  _getch();
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: AFAIK ни в какой, т. к. он в текущем виде не скомпилируется. Но вижу, что вы уже в курсе и исправляете :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Здесь нет никакого полиморфизма: ни статического, ни динамического.  Здесь нет ни наследования, ни перегруженных функций, ни шаблонных функций.

Полиморфизм означает много форм.

Здесь же имеется один класс - одна форма. Здесь есть лишь статическое связывание вызовов методов класса с объектом, имеющим статический тип данного класса.

Comment: Я тоже пытался найти и не нашел

Comment: @program23 Пусть препод участвует в дискуссиях на этом сайте.:) Мы ему покажем "кузькину мать".:)

Answer (score 1):

Во всех подобных строчках (оператор `<<` перегружен):

`cout << "Таймер: " << timer << endl;`

Comment: Это никакого отношения к определению класса не имеет.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow И где в вопросе слова "определение класса"?